# HTAccess Url rewriting rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to simply the access to my `API` with a `.htaccess` file and I'm facing an issue.

For example, what I'd like to achieve is:

- User reaches `http://localhost/teammngr/user/photos/secrethash` and is automatically redirected to `http://localhost/teammngr/user/photos.php?sid=secrethash`.
- User reaches `http://localhost/teammngr/user/config/secrethash` and is automatically redirected to `http://localhost/teammngr/user/config.php?sid=secrethash`.
- User reaches `http://localhost/teammngr/team/members/secrethash` and is automatically redirected to `http://localhost/teammngr/team/members.php?sid=secrethash`.

If the user wants to reach these files directly, it is supposed to be possible.
Moreover, the url `http://localhost/teammngr/` will be under a subdomain like `http://team.mywebsite.com/`.

So far, I've made the following `.htaccess` file, but it keeps throwing a **`500` error** on my server.
To be clear, this file is not in the root directory but in a sub dir.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /teammngr

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^user/([a-z_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$   /user/$1.php?sid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^team/([a-z_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$   /team/$1.php?sid=$2 [L]
```

Where did I make a mistake ?

Thanks for your precious help.

Comment: Why do you have `RewriteBase /teammngr`. None of your URLs have `teammngr` in it.

Comment: @anubhava you beat me to it haha :)

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake in the psot. Let me edit that. Updated

Comment: @Manitoba have you made sure **`mod_rewrite`** is enabled? Try removing your second **`RewriteRule`** and see if you still get any errors?

Comment: Still got the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` is only applicable to very next `RewriteRule`. To avoid repeated `RewriteCond` before every rule you can have a separate rule to ignore requests for files and directories. Also remove `/` from your target URIs.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /teammngr/

# ignore requests for files and directories from rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/([\w-]+)/?$ user/$1.php?sid=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^team/(\w+)/([\w-]+)/?$ team/$1.php?sid=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: +1 the only other issue I could think of would be if mod_rewrite was not enabled for his case aside from that your answer clears it up specially with the inclusion of `-MultiViews`!

Comment: Thanks @Prix, I added `-MultiViews` since PHP file names were similar to URI path but you're right reason for 500 could also be `mod_rewrite` not enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still got the error but `mod_rewrite` is enabled on my server.

Comment: ok check your Apache error.log and see what exact error line is shown for this 500

Comment: Problem solved. Apparently `Options +FollowSymlinks` should no be present in the `.htaccess` because it has already been enabled in the `Apache conf`.

Comment: Ah ok, probably your Apache config didn't allow options to be used in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /teammngr

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^user/([a-z_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$   user/$1.php?sid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^team/([a-z_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$   team/$1.php?sid=$2 [L]
```